Where can I find the file my flutter app created?
I'm trying to make a very simple app in Flutter (for my Android phone, Xiaomi 13T).  It's supposed to run in the background and immediately set an alarm if I get a particular type of email from my Gmail.  I figured the first thing that I should do is set up the persistence and a basic UI. Here's the code to add the file:
void add_to_file(String email, String search_term, String sender) async {
  final filename = './alert_file.txt';
  new File(filename).create(recursive: true);
  final f =  File(filename).writeAsString('$email,$search_term,$sender\n',mode: FileMode.append);  
  print('added file');

}

I connected the app to my phone, flutter build apk, flutter install, and ran in debug mode from VS Code and got the following:
I/ImeTracker(26100): com.example.email_alarm:1215632d: onCancelled at PHASE_CLIENT_APPLY_ANIMATION
I/flutter (26100): added file

Based on this, my function is running, but I can't find the created file anywhere.  I also can't find the com.example.email_alarm folder in my phone's app data.  The program works as intended when I run it as a desktop app.  When I run it in my laptop's chrome, it just hangs when I press the button to trigger the add_to_file function.
Is the app writing to a file? If so, where is it?
